# Copying next sibling html content in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Whenever overlay element is clicked and startCopying() method is called, the text from copyTextTag should be copied in the pasteTextTag element.

The text should be copied in HTML format and pasted as HTML format. 
Also there are multiple copyTextTag but pasteTextTag is one, so the text must be copied only of clicked overlays copyTextTag div.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="copyTextTag">
        svlgmdfgndfjkgndjkgndkjgnerjkgndkgnjdkjgndjkgnffsdf<br/>Test 1          
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" ng-click="homectrl.startCopying($event)"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="copyTextTag">
        svlgmdfgndfjkgndjkgndkjgnerjkgndkgnjdkjgndjkgnffsdf<br/>Test 1          
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" ng-click="homectrl.startCopying($event)"></div>
</div>


/* Area where the copied text should be pasted */
<div class="pasteTextTag"></div>

/* Angular Code */
function startCopying(evt){     
    console.log(angular.element(evt.currentTarget)) //not working       
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this... https://jsfiddle.net/x5zfe520/2/

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <body>

    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="copyTextTag">
            svlgmdfgndfjkgndjkgndkjgnerjkgndkgnjdkjgndjkgnffsdf<br/>Test 1          
        </div>
        <div class="overlay" ng-click="startCopying($event)">Copy</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="copyTextTag">
            svlgmdfgndfjkgndjkgndkjgnerjkgndkgnjdkjgndjkgnffsdf<br/>Test 2          
        </div>
        <div class="overlay" ng-click="startCopying($event)">Copy</div>
    </div>

    /* Area where the copied text should be pasted */
    <div class="pasteTextTag"></div>
    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {       
        $scope.startCopying = function(evt){
         var copiedHtml = angular.element(angular.element(evt.currentTarget).parent('.col-md-4').children()[0]).html();
         console.log(copiedHtml) ;
         angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName("pasteTextTag")).html(copiedHtml);
        }
    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

bind the pasting text with html template. assign that scope variable whenever clicked

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="copyTextTag">
        svlgmdfgndfjkgndjkgndkjgnerjkgndkgnjdkjgndjkgnffsdf<br/>Test 1          
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" ng-click="homectrl.startCopying($event)"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="copyTextTag">
        svlgmdfgndfjkgndjkgndkjgnerjkgndkgnjdkjgndjkgnffsdf<br/>Test 1          
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" ng-click="homectrl.startCopying($event)"></div>
</div>


/* Area where the copied text should be pasted */
<div class="pasteTextTag" ng-bind="paste"></div>

/* Angular Code */
function startCopying(evt){     
    $scope.paste = evt.target.previousElementSibling.innerHTML;     
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ru8tuv1v/

Comment: This too works fine but only problem here is I am not able to copy the content as an HTML, it just copies the content as text. Even the html tags are copied as a simple text.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a fiddle which is working as expected.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/u1cxe5st/
```

you are not giving any text in the below div , so you were not clicking on the proper place to fire the click event.

```
<div class="overlay" ng-click="homectrl.startCopying($event)">Click Me</div>
```

Comment: I am just seeing the code I have written and its not working, where have you pasted the text in which div

Comment: go to the link that I have provided, In the top left corner you will see your HTML and in the bottom left corner is your angular code. in the bottom right is the output which is generated based on HTML. if you click on `Click me` then you will see output in chrome console.